# Laravel get latest records with group by with multiple column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Hello I'm new in Laravel I'm stuck  in a complex query with Laravel eloquent

Here is my messages table structure

```
---|-----------|-------------|--------
ID | sender_id | receiver_id | message
---|-----------|-------------|--------
 1 |   1       |   2         | Hello 
 2 |   1       |   2         | Hey hello reply
 3 |   2       |   1         | Good
 4 |   3       |   2         | Hey GOOD Morning
 5 |   3       |   2         | good night
```

I want to retrieve recent chat from messages table either user is sender or receiver I want to retrieve with a groupBy using multiple columns and with latest only one message

Like for User 2 (Either sender or receiver)

```
-----------|-------------|---------------
 sender_id | receiver_id | message
-----------|-------------|---------------
   2       |   1         | Good
   3       |   2         | good night
```

Here is my eloquent query

```
$user = auth()->user(); //User_id 2 based on logged in user either sender or reciever
Message::where('user_id', $user->id)
        ->orWhere('receiver_id', $user->id)
        ->select('user_id','receiver_id')
        ->groupBy('user_id','receiver_id')
       ->get();
```

Result

```
all: [
   App\Models\Message {
        user_id: 1,
        receiver_id: 2,
   }, // don't want this record
   App\Models\Message {
        user_id: 2,
        receiver_id: 1,
   },
   App\Models\Message {
        user_id: 3,
        receiver_id: 2,
   },
],
```

If I try to use latest() method then it's showing error timestamp is there in a table

> Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]:
>
> Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column

I don't want to update `mysql_strict` mode in `config/database.php`

it's not working properly can anyone help me or any good suggestion or idea

Any help will appreciate

Comment: What exactly is not working properly? Is there some error, the output is not what you expected? For getting latest records you can use `->latest()`, which requires timestamps in your table. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

Comment: what's not working? do you get any results?

Comment: This is going to be a real pain to handle using Laravel syntax.  Honestly, you might want to handle this from a stored procedure, or use native SQL, and maybe upgrade to MySQL 8+.

Comment: In your example, are we looking at the result for user 2?

Comment: Provide current result and your expected result in your question description

Comment: I just update my question can you please look at once again @Rudolph

Comment: I just update my question can you please look at once again @Strawberry

Comment: In your example, are we looking at the result for user 2?

Comment: yes, user 2 is either sender or receiver @Strawberry

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Already updated. if you have a solution, please help @Strawberry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you figure out how to express this in Laravel?

```
**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

CREATE TABLE my_table
(ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,sender_id INT NOT NULL
,receiver_id INT NOT NULL
,message VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,1,2,'Hello'),
(2,1,2,'Hey hello reply'),
(3,2,1,'Good'),
(4,3,2,'Hey GOOD Morning'),
(5,3,2,'good night');

---

**Query #1**

SELECT a.*
  FROM my_table a
  JOIN
     ( SELECT MAX(id) id
         FROM my_table
        WHERE 2 IN(sender_id,receiver_id)
        GROUP
           BY LEAST(sender_id,receiver_id)
            , GREATEST(sender_id,receiver_id)
     ) b
    ON b.id = a.id;

| ID  | sender_id | receiver_id | message    |
| --- | --------- | ----------- | ---------- |
| 3   | 2         | 1           | Good       |
| 5   | 3         | 2           | good night |

---
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Comment: SQL query working fine, Thanks @Strawberry now I have to convert into Laravel query